# Set phone color themes programmatically within app in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, themes, overriding

Is it possible to set the theme of the phone to dark/light or change the accent color within an app? Even if it's only for the life cycle of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, you can only change the theme for your app.

Comment: Do you have an example on how I might go about doing that? I only need to change the theme for the app.